# Cannot retain post variables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a form in codeigniter if user clicks on the submit button he will be  redirected to the user profile page. But in my case user is redirected to profile page but when i reload profile page then all the data i.e. userId and name which i posted from previous form are blank.

Here is my code:

```
public function Profile() {
        $uId = decode($this->input->post('_id'));
        $name = decode($this->input->post('_name'));
        $this->data['ID'] = encode($uId);
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('web/profile', $this->data, true);
        $this->load->view('web/layout', $this->data);
    }
```

Comment: because on refresh there is no `$this->input->post('_id')` and `$this->input->post('_name')` available, it available only at submit.

Comment: Can hidden field will solve this issue?

Comment: on refresh page hidden field will also goes reset. so you need to store `_id` and `_name` somewhere if you need it after refresh.

Comment: saving it in cookies

Comment: then every time you refresh the page , send post parameter `_id` and `_name` which you stored

Comment: Use session to store userinfo and get that information from session check below url https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The code you show forces readers to make lots of assumptions. Please show the code for the view that contains the form the submit button is posting.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the `UserID` and `name` in a session variable can solve your problem. After loading just destroy the used session variable.